# phonegap - {"error":"no keystore file attached"}

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to use phonegap build API service to add an android key.  According to their documentation we need to submit the details in the below format.

```
https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android
{
    "title":"Android Key",
    "default":false,
    "id":2,
    "alias":"release",
    "link":"/api/v1/keys/android/2",
    "locked":false
}
```

I am trying to call the API from my localhost computer.  With the help of keytool I already created a keystore file 'D:\app.mykeystore'.  If I give this path in the link it says 'no keystore file attached'.

How can I upload/add the android keystore file to phonegap under my account?

Comment: key.store=d:\app\mykeystore.jks
    key.alias=mykeyalias

Comment: @Martin - nope. still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally make it work with the below code

```
$keys = array(
  "title" => 'Release-Key',
  "alias" => 'mykeyrelease',
  "key_pw" => '222222',
  "keystore_pw" => '222222'
);

$data = array(
  'data' => json_encode($keys),
  'keystore' => '@D:\mykey.keystore'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

The keystore file should has .keystore as extension.